# personalizara FOSUserBundle en symfony 4

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, symfony4, fos-user-bundle

hola espero puedan ayudarme, siempre hemos usado este `bundle` `FOSUserBundle`
en `symfony 2` ahora que estamos pasando todo a `symfony 4` no podemos personalizar los formularios, ya logre que tomara estilos agregando `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/app.css') }}">` en el `layout` ubicado en `vendor\friendsofsymfony\Resources\views` pero no creo que sea la manera mas optima. 
saludos y gracias por su tiempo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no es la manera mas óptima de realizarlo, mejor es haciendo overriding de los templates y estos los ubicas en la carpeta templates/bundles/FOSUserBundle/{carpetas}

De esta forma puedes modificar todo y no lo pierdes en futuras actualizaciones del bundle.

Saludos,

Comment: excelente muchas gracias